# empty class definition vs empty class declaration, VS2012 vs VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

As I want to create a new empty C# class in VS2012, I was given two options like shown below:

[image]
[image]

What bothers me here is that both of them are actually having the same info, "An empty class **definition**" but there are two of them.

But when I open my VS2013 to do the same thing, I was also given two options (as shown below) but having different info:

[image]
[image]

one is **declaration** and another is **definition**

So, these are my questions:

1. Why do I have multiple Empty C# class templates in my VS2012 with the same name and info? Are there any differences between them?
2. Why do I have different multiple Empty C# class templates in my VS2013 as compared to VS2012 (with the same name but different info)? Are there really any differences between them (because I cannot notice any)?

Comment: Probably just got left from various installs; you can probably just clean them up - they are in the locations shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found where the .vstemplate class are actually stored. However, as I open the ...ItemTemplates/CSharp/Code/1033/Class folder here, I can only find one .vstemplate having `Class` name. Is this expected?

Comment: VS2015Update1 and there is `Code File` and `Class`. The first one creates an empty `.cs` file, while the second one put some using statements and namespace and class declaration.

Comment: Does it also applied to VS2012/13? It seems then that there is no significant differences between the two, but one template is more "complete" than the other. Can I put it that way?

Comment: I don't have VS2012/2013 installed to check the problem. Why does it matter to you? You can write many lines of code in 25 minutes passed since you have asked this question in both templates!

Comment: @dotctor that is exactly what I want to know, whether it will matter to me if I use one instead of another under certain condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a slight difference. Actually it are just two empty C# class files, with only some documentation as difference. If you look closely, you will see that one template is in the Web folder, the other in the General folder. I think this is just for the ease of use in common scenarios: you don't have to switch to General to create a new class when you have a Web project.

Comment: Do you mean between the two classes in my VS2012 one is from Web another is from General?

Comment: I found both in my Visual C# Items, under the sub-tree item `Code`

Comment: The "web" related ones usually have `using System.Web;`, which: this does not seem to

Comment: Not in my case. It are just plain C# code files here.

Comment: @ian. Yes. Here I have two items. One in General and one in Web.

Comment: I see, so it can be different from installation to installation, is it? Mine is only having one .vstemplate here (VS2012), but show two of the `Class`. Strange huh?

Comment: Indeed. What happens if you search for "Class" in the  search box?

Comment: There is only one `Class.vstemplate` here, but I can see two `Class.cs`

Comment: And yes! one of them is actually under folder Code\1033\WebClass, the other being in the Code\1033\Class! Does this make any difference if I want to create web/non web app?

Comment: Yes, but my question is more of: does it make any difference?

Comment: Ok, great. Last question: and how about the two templates in VS2013?

Comment: What about them? Their description? I guess that is just another way of putting it.

Comment: @Rahul: please don't randomly put code blocks around words.